# MongoDB query not working as expected, returning missing items

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a query that searches for `ItemA` documents, which have a field `itemB`. The query returns all `ItemA` documents, but only with `itemB` properties that have `image.deleted = false`.

```
const itemAs = await ItemA.aggregate([
    { $match: { "itemB.deleted": false } },
    {
        $project: {
            itemB: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$itemB",
                    as: "itemB",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$itemB.deleted", false] }
                }
            },
            date: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

The problem with this, is that if all `itemB` documents have deleted set to `true` for a certain `ItemA`, then this query will not return that `ItemA`. `ItemA` should be returned always, regardless of how many of its `itemB` have deleted set to `true`.

My schema:

```
const itemASchema = new Schema({
  itemBs: [
    {
      url: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      },
      deleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

How can I fix this query to not only return `itemB` elements that are set to `false`, but also always return the `ItemA` document, even if all of its `itemBs` are set to `true`?

Comment: Something wrong with your specifications. You filter by `images.deleted : false`, but in your schema there is no any images. Your query should always return `itemA` ([look](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fIBj0Or9C4f))

Comment: I've made a change to OP. Sorry about that, I was trying to make this a generic question, I missed the `images`.

Comment: If you remove first `$match` operator, it solves your problem?

Comment: Wow, yes. Thank you.